# Visual Studio 2008 debugging problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

When I set up a breakpoint, it works, but when I try to step to next line of code, it leaves the debug mode (as though I clicked continue button).

Comment: Could you place piece of code that is not debuggable

Comment: What are you clicking/pressing to step to the next line of code?  There may be different keys set up for this depending on your VS settings.

Comment: Usually F10 use for next line.

Comment: Can you actually set a breakpoint on the line you want to execute next? It might be that the line you expect to be next is actually out of the execution path.

Comment: It's been four days.  Still haven't tried the hotfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a documented problem with the debugger in VS2008 SP1.  There's a hotfix available that fixes this particular problem, as well as several debugger issues when debugging multi-threaded code.  Recommended, download [is here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty difficult as we don't know enough detail.
1. Are you sure you are pressing F10 or Step to step to the next line?
2. Is this piece of code unreachable?
3. Is the code in another assembly that might be out of date?

Comment: Yes, everything I press F10, code is reachable and it's code in the same assembly. I can simulate stepping by inserting breakpoints in the fly (I stop at breakpoint, then insert a breakpoint a few lines later, and so on)